# Pass "False" Value when Checkbox is not Checked via Upsert in AMPscript

Tags: ampscript, html, dataextensions

I am creating a custom profile center and need to update a Data Extension with the value of a checkbox. I can get it to post "true" when the checkbox is checked, but when it's not checked I want it to pass "false" as they are unsubscribing from a publication.

I've tried `IsNull()`, `IsNullDefault()` and `empty()` AMPscript functions to no avail. One solution I tried was this:

```
IsNull(IsNullDefault(RequestParameter('interest_sewing'),"false"))
```

or

```
IsNull(RequestParameter('interest_sewing'))
```

But both always returns false. Here is a checkbox example:

```
<label>
  <input id="attribute1" name="attribute1" type="checkbox" value="true">  attribute1
</label>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the upsert(), it may be worth to run a check on the variable and pass false if true is not passed.

```
Set @att1 = RequestParameter('interest_sewing')
If @att1 != 'true' Then
   Set @att1 = 'false'
Else EndIf

UpsertData("SendDE",1,"_SubscriberKey",_SubscriberKey,"interest_sewing",@att1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it technically works. I was hoping to do it using one of the ET's native functions but this works fine. I appreciate the response.